# Is there a way I can seamlessly replace a Texture that's in Unity Resources, in runtime, without having it un-referenced in renderers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources

I want to replace many textures in a Unity 5.0 game, at runtime.
But I don't want all the renderers that use that texture to loose the reference to that texture.
So I want to swap the global texture without it being un-referenced.
I could probably loop trough every single renderer and re-refrence the texture but that's gonna be hugely demanding code to run and probably a mess aswell.
Maybe there's a way to rewrite the actual content of the texture without unloading it?

I know I can do it in a very dirty way by referencing the texture for every renderer individually but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a system that all gameObjects when instantiated recive a reference to the same material instance, than you just need to change the material texture to affect all of them

Answer (score 0):

You could probably e.g. use [`Shader.SetGlobalTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.SetGlobalTexture.html) to exchange a texture globally for each and every instance of any shader that has the given property

=> This would of course require a custom shader that provides such a dedicated property in order to only affect you actual targets.

---

Is there a certain reason why to stick to specifically Unity 5.0?

That version is quite outdated

Comment: Well I'm going with just finding all the sharedMaterials, changing the texture for those.
But now I'm running into the problem of not knowing the texture id's, not having access to UnityEditor or ShaderUtil classes so I'll probably just need to hope there's no textures that don't go by the usual naming scheme.